# VirtualBox host-only network suddenly stopped working , no interface available inside

Tags: networking, virtualbox, kernel-modules

I'm unable to setup host-only network in virtualbox suddenly , please see my screenshot , there's no entry in "Name" comboBox

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the *main window* of VirtualBox go to `File->Preferences`, select `Network` and click the icon on the right, showing a card with a `+` sign.

Comment: That was nice !